# Why does the mollified function converge uniformly to the original $W^{1,\infty}$ function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, uniform-convergence

I'm studying Evans' PDE book and on page 294 it states that if we have $u \in W^{1, \infty } (\mathbb R^n)$ and has compact support, and take $\eta _\epsilon$ as the standard mollifier, then $\eta _\epsilon \ast u$ converges to $u$ uniformly as $\epsilon \to 0$.

I have trouble understanding this since I only know this is true if $u$ is continuous. And I tried to apply the proof for $u \in W^{1, \infty } (\mathbb R^n)$ but failed.

Comment: But if $u \in W^{1,\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N)$, then $u$ is continuous, in fact even Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: @gerw Yes, but that paragraph is just trying to prove your statement, so I can't just assume that. Or do you know any proof of it without using the statement that I asked about?

Answer (score 1):

Continuity of $u$ follows from Morrey's inequality which was proved a few pages earlier in the book: a function in $W^{1,p}$, $p>n$, has a continuous representative, with which it is identified.

---

For completeness, a proof of uniform convergence.
Continuity and compact support imply uniform continuity. So, for any fixed $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta$ such that if $r<\delta$,  all the values of $u$ involved in the integral $\eta_r* u(x)$ are within $\epsilon$ of $u(x)$. Since mollification averages these values, $|\eta_r* u(x)-u(x)|\le \epsilon$ as desired.

Comment: In the previous result true if we do not assume that u has compact support? I guess that maybe there is a way of approximate it via compactly supported functions but Im not sure. Can someone shed some light into this point?